# Google play developper two versions in the same time

Tags: android, google-play-console

I would like to be able to test two versions of my app at the same time. With apple there are no issues, on TestFlight you can switch between builds, but with Google I can't find how to do it.

I have a version of the app with bug fix and another one with big features.

I tried to generate APKs, but there are issues with the payment and this is a really complex process

Answer (score 0):

Only one App with same packageName can be installed simultaneously, so....it's not possible.
But you can compile both and install them separately in different moments.
From Google Console Website (logging with approrpiate rights/credentials) you can choose which Bundle/APK download.